Error loading images in a React + p5.js project
THE ERROR: This error appears if I use loadImage() function, even if I didn't use the image loaded anywhere else. In this case it is the background image, but even loading images I just want to use on certain assets, logs the same error. I have also tried other image formats to check, but again, same error.
My App.css still loads and renders the background plain black, but doesn't show any of the p5/Matter.js assets.

THE CODE: The problematic area of code can be found in the p.preload() function inside function sketch(), right after the variable declarations.
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import p5 from 'p5';
import Matter from 'matter-js'
import './App.css'
import Ball from "./components/Ball.jsx";
import Boundary from "./components/Boundary.jsx";
import Box from "./components/Box.jsx";

let Engine = Matter.Engine;
let World = Matter.Composite;
let Mouse = Matter.Mouse;
let MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;
let Collision = Matter.Collision;
let ground, ball, world, engine, mCon, leftWall, rightWall, collision;
let boxes = [];
let score = 0;
let timer = 42;
let bgImage, monsterImage, ballImage;

function sketch(p) {
    p.preload = function() {
        bgImage = p.loadImage('background.webp');
    }

    p.setup = function() {
        const canvas = p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
        engine = Engine.create();
        world = engine.world;

        const canvasMouse = Mouse.create(canvas.elt);
        canvasMouse.pixelRatio = p.pixelDensity();
        const options = {
            mouse: canvasMouse,
        }
        mCon = MouseConstraint.create(engine, options);

        ground = new Boundary(p.width/2, p.height-10, p.width, 20, world);
        leftWall = new Boundary(10, p.height/2, 20, p.height, world);
        rightWall = new Boundary(p.width - 10, p.height/2, 20, p.height, world);
        ball = new Ball(p.width/2, p.height - 100, 30, world);

        World.add(world, [mCon]);
    }

    setInterval(spawnBoxes, 1500);

    function spawnBoxes() {
        if(boxes.length > 7) {
            World.remove(engine.world, boxes[0].body);
            boxes.splice(0, 1);
        }
        let xLoc = Math.random() * p.width;
        let yLoc = Math.random() * (p.height/2 - 100) + 100;
        boxes.push(new Box(xLoc, yLoc, 50, 50, world));
    }

    p.windowResized = function() {
        p.resizeCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
    }

    p.draw = function () {
        p.background(51);
        Engine.update(engine);
        rightWall.show(p);
        leftWall.show(p);
        ground.show(p);
        ball.show(p);
        p.textSize(32);
        p.fill("white");
        p.text(`Score: ${score}`, 50, 50);

        for(let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            boxes[i].show(p);
        }

        if(ball.body.position.y < 0 || ball.body.position.y > p.height + 50 || ball.body.position.x < 0 || ball.body.position.x > p.width + 50) {
            ball.reset(p);
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            if(Collision.collides(ball.body, boxes[i].body)) {
                console.log("HIT ", i);
                World.remove(engine.world, boxes[i].body);
                boxes.splice(i, 1);
                ball.reset(p);
                score += 5;
            }
        }
    }
}

function App() {
    const p5Container = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const p5Instance = new p5(sketch, p5Container.current);

        return() => {
            p5Instance.remove();
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div ref={p5Container} className="container">
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;

I am not very sure what the error even means to be honest and where to start debugging.
Would appreciate any help, thanks!
I don't have any errors using an online hosted image. But the docs seem to say that as long as the image url is relative, it should work? For reference, my final project will be hosted on Firebase.

Are you running a web server to host background.webp, and you're able to access the image on your base server URL, e.g. http://localhost:3000/background.webp? Where is this file located when you run it locally? Are you using create React app or webpack to develop the React app? Check your network tab for image loading errors.

@ggorlen I'll check the network tab. When I tried hosting the picture using an http-server I got some CORS errors. It hosted the image on a different port which is probably the issue.
Truth be told, I wanted to know if there's any other way apart from a local server to resolve this issue? If I host the photo on a local server, when I ultimately deploy it and share the link, I assume other devices will have issues displaying the image.
I am using Vite to create my React app.
Image location in project structure is at the root, with App.js.

Yeah, if it's on a different port you'll need to enable CORS for that request. If Vite, then you can proxy the request to your other server, or host it at the same origin with the Vite development server. If you can share your configs and package.json I can see what I can offer.

@ggorlen should I just edit the original post to include my config and package.json? Also hosting it with a Vite development server (will look into how to do that) would mean the functionality remains same even in the production build? As in to solve my issue with a locally hosted image not showing up in the online deployed version.

Yeah, please [edit] the original post to include more details. No need to say "EDIT:", it hasn't been answered yet. As long as the URL in your code points to a valid image in both environments, then it should work both in dev and prod. So you're trying to avoid a situation where you need to hardcode "https://localhost:3000/image.png" into the code specific to dev (although that can be useful for initial debugging), then have to change it to something else whenever you deploy. The dev server needs to be responsible for getting "image.png" served or proxied so it looks just like prod.

See https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options#server-proxy and https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets

Importing images as mentioned in https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets worked easily, thanks! I feel somewhat silly now since it seems that should've been an obvious idea lol.

Great, feel free to post a self answer.
